# Is there a way to change folder for iCloud Drive?

Tags: icloud

The icloud drive is in /users/username/icloud

I want to change that to another folder. How do I do so?

I can do that in dropbox and onedrive.

Comment: Yes;  You open up `iCloud` then click on *Options* and change the location of the `iCloud Photo` storage location.  Since photos are the only thing you can backup on Windows that should answer your question.

Comment: No. I want to sync other stuffs first.

Comment: Why not just make a shortcut wherever you'd rather it be?

Comment: It shows up in Windows Favourites anyway, in the sidebar of every window.

Comment: I like to store stuffs on my d drive not on my c drive

Comment: The duplicate page link was deleted. Please reopen.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'll assume this is about iCloudDrive for Windows (you don't mention that explicitly in your question). If that's the case, follow these steps:

1. Disable iCloud Drive from the Control Panel (please really do this, otherwise it will mess things up)
2. **Move** (not copy) your iCloudDrive directory (`C:\Users\<username>\iCloudDrive`) to the new location.
3. Open a command prompt and type: `mklink /J "C:\Users\<username>\iCloudDrive" "<new destination>"` This creates a junction (sort of a shortcut, but more powerfull) from the old location to the new location.
4. Reboot your computer and everything should be fine

Comment: When you uncheck iCloud Diive in the iCloud control panel (6.1.1 on W10), the iCloud Drive is deleted (so it's difficult to move it while it doesn't exist anymore). Instead, you´ll have to kill the iCloud Drive process. Also note that the destination folder you choose will appear as iCloud Drive in the Explorer (the real directory name can still be seen in a command prompt).

Comment: May I suggest that you use `%USERPROFILE%` rather than `C:\Users\<username>` (no text substitution necessary nor assumption about the location of `\Users`

Comment: You can have a GUI to accomplish the link if you download Steam Mover http://www.traynier.com/software/steammover
1. Point the left side to C:\users\yourname\
2. Point the right side to D:\
3. Uncheck iCloud Drive in iCloud control panel
4. Manually create directory iCloudDrive in C:\users\yourname\
5. Refresh the Steam Mover UI, click the right arrow to create the link
6. Re-enable iCloud Drive in iCloud control panel. Files should appear in D:\iCloudDrive