# How to disable iCloud Drive on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, icloud

In this question: [Is there a way to change folder for iCloud Drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/883970/is-there-a-way-to-change-folder-for-icloud-drive)
a caveat was listed that in Windows 10, iCloud must be disabled.  However, the options to disable iCloud are no longer in the control panel as stated.

How can I be sure to disable every process associated with iCloud?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to change folder for iCloud Drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/883970/is-there-a-way-to-change-folder-for-icloud-drive)

Comment: I know that, I can't help with the fact you do not having the reputation, to submit a comment.  I can do something about the fact this question, being a duplicate, by flagging it.  This isn't how you improve an existing question or answer an exiting answer or comment requesting more information be added to an answer

Comment: answer questions that don't require submitting a comment and/or answer the original question with a answer that adds significant information.  Your answer does not do that.

Comment: I thought that finding how to properly disable iCloud service was significant since the procedure won't work it you don't do it.  Not so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45439/discussion-between-grldsndrs-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution:

- opening the task manager,
- selecting the start up tab,
- disabling the iCloud start-up processes then
- restarting the machine.

After I rebooted, I followed the instructions in the previously answered post and it worked